# Mocking an incoming request in to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, routes, mocking, cucumber

I am using FactoryGirl to mock my models for both unit (RSpec) tests and integration (Cucumber) tests. When creating a `News` factory I create a random image URL, which obviously doesn't exist within the project. When running a Selenium test this get's picked up as a 404.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :news do
    title { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    image { Faker::Internet.relative_url ".jpg" }
    body { Faker::Lorem.paragraphs.join "\r\n\r\n" }

    before :create do
      Timecop.freeze Faker::Date.time
    end

    after :create do
      Timecop.return
    end

    after :build do |article|
      # Somehow mock a 200 response for #{article.image}
    end

    factory :published_news do
      published true
    end
  end
end
```

What's the best way to mock a response for my image?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the mock in the test that fetches that image, not in the factory.

Either that or just provide a static image file in the image link (you don't need to test that your model can accept different URL strings).

Comment: OK, so if I had to write the mock in the test, how would I do that? I've found libraries that mock requests, but not routing.

Comment: Personally, there's little benefit in mocking this. Just create a standard image, put it in your `/assets/images/` folder and reference that in the factory so that it always produces the news object with that image: `image '/assets/test_image.jpg'`  You're not testing anything really by having that dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return 200, can you not just return it like this?

```
after :build do |article|
 ["200", "OK"]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just only added in your specs the following:

```
describe Zomg do
  it 'should get ok' do 
    stub_request(:any, "http://factory-generated-url-here/").to_return(body: '', status: 200)

   # you stuff with request        
  end   
end
```

thanks [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock)